# CURL not working in node.js in CentOS 5.7, but works fine in debian 2.6.32-5

Tags: centos5, curl, node.js

working on an app in node.js, On the test server (debian 2.6.32-5) it works flawlessly, on CentOS 5.7 I get an error.

using the curlrequest node.js library, and the error that comes up is "failed to initialize".
I tested curl from the command line and it works fine. I'm thinking it might be a permissions problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with --no-keepalive being used in the curlrequest package. The version of curl that is installed on the CentOS machine doesn't support it. Removing that solved the problem.

Comment: this issue has been solved in the latest version of the curlrequest package